# WPF Entity Framework binding to navigation property not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-4

I have a viewmodel with a Customer property bound to an Entity Framework object.  The customer object has multiple navigation properties to other tables.  My view displays properly if there is already an existing record in one of the dependent tables and I can edit and save, but when I try to add a new object to the Customer property like:

Customer.BillingDetail = new CustomerBillingDetail();

The view will not bind to the new object even though the viewmodel Customer property is populated with a blank object.  So when I go to save, none of the entered values are persisted to the viewmodel, it still has the blank object.

So, how do I get the view and viewmodel to communicate on the addition of a new object to the navigation property?

Is there something I'm missing in the viewmodel for tracking the property change of the Customer navigation properties?

Thanks,
-Sid.

Comment: You probably need to add it to the context. Use context.CreateObject to create the billingdetail.

Comment: It's the view that doesn't know about the new object.  The binding has to be between my viewmodel and view.  So how do I update the Customer property on my viewmodel, that binds correctly if a record already exists, but doesn't when I add a blank to the navigation property?  I'm sure it has to have something to do with a property changed event, but how do you do this with a navigation property?

Comment: I believe your issue is that BillingDetail is initially null and breaks the binding. Google "WPF Binding to null values" for some help. Implementing a Fallback value or using TargetNullValue may be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your EF objects do not implement INotifyChanged and do not use ObservableCollections

Answer (score 0):

Just clear me one one thing, when you bind the view with the values in customer object and make some changes in any of the binded control. Does that change persist in the database. If not then You must try to bind the property with **TwoWay** mode.

It helps to update your customer object from the binded control.

Comment: Yes, the change persists as long as the navigation property already had a record existing in the database to bind to.  I have a "flag" field in the main customer record which indicates if they are a billing customer, etc...  So when the user selects the checkbox to indicate that they are a billing customer there isn't an existing billingdetail record.  So I create a new CustomerBillingDetail object on the viewmodel Customer.BillingDetail property.  But when I go to save the BillingDetail property is still blank, it doesn't have any of the values I typed into the view.